# Sistema de Backup em Php e Mysql (com Codeigniter)

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, backup

Pretendendo colocar no meu software um sistema de backup de banco de dados, onde o usuário irá realizar esse backup manualmente. Só que nunca fiz esse procedimento, e estou utilizando o framework Codeigniter. Alguém poderia me diz a lógica em como fazer tal procedimento?

Comment: Já existe uma resposta para isso aqui no site, reabri sua pergunta e marquei como duplicata. Siga o link ali no topo para encontrar a resposta.